# hibernate save not working springboot

Tags: hibernate, rest, spring-boot

We are trying to save entity from Hibernate `session.save()` method but in log it not even generating query and not storing in db also. we are trying with rest with springboot.

### PatientServiceImpl:

```
 public Patient createPatient(Patient patient) {
            Session session = SessionUtil.getSession();
        System.out.println("hiii" + patient);
        session.save(patient);
        System.out.println("hiiii");
            return null;
        }
```

### PatientService

```
@Path("/patientservice")
public interface PatientService { @Path("/patients")
@POST
public Patient createPatient(Patient patient);
}
```

but I am able get records from get with criteria methods.

below log:
2018-02-11 11:58:32.883  INFO 2188 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .c.i.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl : HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
2018-02-11 11:58:33.201  INFO 2188 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
2018-02-11 11:58:33.256  INFO 2188 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
hiiiPatient [pid=2, pname=bhas, page=29]
hiiii

Comment: can you post your Patient model .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the flush() to actually transmit your object(patient)

```
public Patient createPatient(Patient patient) {
    Session session = SessionUtil.getSession();
    System.out.println("hiii" + patient);
    session.save(patient);
    // Right after the save
    session.flush(patient); // This should save the object to database
    System.out.println("hiiii");
    // Not a good idea to return null. Try using Optional in java8
    return null; 
}
```